# CakePHP: Public Profile for Users

Tags: cakephp, profile, public

I've created a back end where users can edit and preview their own data, but what parameters would I have to use in order to create a template for public profiles where if I were to visit any user it would display their information and not the current logged in user?

Comment: users/view/other_user_id ?

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you would need the ID of the user in the database. That way you can take that ID, look up the user in the database, and return a User object to the view you're rendering. This is typically solved by using RESTful routes (here's a [CakePHP doc on REST](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html) and here's [a good document on it in the context of Rails](http://b-simple.de/download/restful_rails_en.pdf)) to identify the resource you're talking about. For example, your route for a given user might look like this:

`http://example.com/users/1`

where `1` is the ID of the user you want to view. In your controller, you can then do something like:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $recipe = $this->Users->get($id);
    $user->set([
        'user' => $user
    ]);
}
```

which will pass a user variable into your view.

Obviously you would have a different route entirely for the editing/viewing of one's own personal data.